# Make a Bootstrap form in Google Script

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script

We are trying to make a form using Bootstrap 3, and them the response should go to a Google Spreadsheet, we tried to do but is not working, our problems are load bootstrap css in google script html page and when the button is pressed put fields information in Google Spreadsheet.

Thank you.

Google Script

```
    function doGet(e) {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
    }

    function setData(data) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1uU2GtTjN8SYKQduar4y4n2u0EGeQFaznRddtrmNSYN8").getActiveSheet();
      var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
      ss.getRange(lastRow+1, 1).setValue(data[0]);
      Logger.log(data[0]);
      return 0

}
```

Java script and Html

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getData).setData();
  });

  function getData(data) {
    var data = [];
    data[0] = document.getElementById("InputName").value;
    data[1] = document.getElementById("InputEmail").value;
    data[2] = document.getElementById("Inputtel").value;
    data[3] = document.getElementById("InputCPFCNPJ").value;
    data[4] = document.getElementById("InputEnterprise").value;
    data[5] = document.getElementById("InputMessage").value;

    google.script.run.setdata(data);
    return 0;
  }

    </script>

    <html lang="pt-br">
        <body>
            <form role="form">

                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="InputName">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputName" placeholder="Nome">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="InputEmail">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="e-mail">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="Inputtel">Telefone</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Inputtel" placeholder="Telefone">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="InputCPFCNPJ">CPF ou CNPJ</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="InputCPFCNPJ" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="InputEnterprise">Empresa</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputEnterprise" placeholder="Empresa">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="InputMessage">Mensagem</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="InputMessage" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="getData();">
                    Enviar
                    </button>
                </div>

            </form>
            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: don't forget to use       `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);`
to get it execute faster :)

Comment: @Renan, what are you using to get access to the spreadsheet? I can't find a Javascript interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to import the bootstrap CSS properly. 
Second you need to call your server side function setData with an upper case D according to your server side declaration.

```
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
function getData(data) {
var data = [];
    data[0] = document.getElementById("InputName").value;
    data[1] = document.getElementById("InputEmail").value;
    data[2] = document.getElementById("Inputtel").value;
    data[3] = document.getElementById("InputCPFCNPJ").value;
    data[4] = document.getElementById("InputEnterprise").value;
    data[5] = document.getElementById("InputMessage").value;
     google.script.run.setData(data);
  }

</script>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <body>
        <form role="form">

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="InputName">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputName" placeholder="Nome">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="InputEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="e-mail">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="Inputtel">Telefone</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Inputtel" placeholder="Telefone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="InputCPFCNPJ">CPF ou CNPJ</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="InputCPFCNPJ" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="InputEnterprise">Empresa</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputEnterprise" placeholder="Empresa">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="InputMessage">Mensagem</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="InputMessage" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="getData();">
                Enviar
                </button>
            </div>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Mestre muito grato!

Comment: Hey its working, but when the button is pressed the page say some page was not foud, and the values do not go to the spreadsheet the [script](https://script.google.com/a/macros/itcld.com.br/s/AKfycbwQHo6EsI4XB2XAx-po0b49ZTJRT_pUv_qUsCR3xz3LCbK6V_5Z/exec) running.